# using Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO to create an Alter Stored Procedure sql Script?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, powershell

The following powershell script seems to generate a "Create" stored procedure script successfully

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("<SERVER>")
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("<Database>")
$proc = $db.StoredProcedures.Item("<StoredProcedure>")
$proc.Script() > testScript.sql
```

Is there anyway to create an "Alter" using a similar approach i.e. changing the scripting options?
I am referencing a SQL Server 2005 environment.

I could always add a statement to replace "CREATE PROC" with "ALTER PROC" but this seems inelegant...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ALTER scripts instead of CREATE scripts using SMO (Server Management Object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159901/how-to-create-alter-scripts-instead-of-create-scripts-using-smo-server-manageme)

Comment: Agree w/ msarchet duplciate question. I would add, third party tools such as Red Gate SQLCompare do this and have a commmand-line interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Powershell script seems to work for me:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null 
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("<SERVER>") 
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("<DATABASE>") 
$proc = $db.StoredProcedures | ?{ $_.Name -eq "<STORED PROC>"} 
$retval = $proc.ScriptHeader($true) + $proc.TextBody 
$retval > testScript.sql
```

Note that the passing true to the following command creates an alter Header:

```
$proc.ScriptHeader($true)
```

Comment: I want to alter a function the same way. I get an error though saying "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" and it seem to be refering to $retval. Suggestions?
Also the testScript.sql file, is this the file containg the modifications you want to make (ie. the alter script). 
Thanks.